# Custom page in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

hi i m new to drupal i want to know that how could i add my custom page for the display the some information which is come from databases, i have create that page in core php (for example information.php)but i want to add that page in drupal 7 how it is possible

looking for the quick and best reply

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be to add a content type "Information" to your drupal site, rename your information.php file to node--information.tpl.php and use the Drupal Database API to get stuff from your database. Finally you'd want to put node--information.tpl.php in your theme/%themename/templates/ folder and add new content with the Content Type "Information".

The best way would be to make a new module. Build your menu structure and add a theming function that calls a template file. When calling the template file using theme(), pass along the data that needs to be displayed.

In addition you might want to check out the Custom Page module: http://drupal.org/project/custompage

Comment: thanks for the reply but it not work i put the my information.php in template folder with replace name node-information.tpl.php and also create one content type name as information and add the content to that type but it does not call my information.tpl.php any declaration is required to it's config file or like similer else.

Comment: Notice the double '-' between node and information: node--information.tpl.php. Make sure the machine name of the content type is 'information'. Drupal matches the machine name of the content type with the name of the PHP Template file.

Comment: Might want to flag this as answered, other people might find this helpful :)