# Adding another PHP file in Drupal

Tags: php, jquery, drupal-7

Hi I've got a question in drupal 7. I'm planning to write my own page with PHP and Jquery.How will i integrate it with DRUPAL? Please help me.

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5402200/2567813

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve that, one of which I am describing below:-

Steps:

1.Create menu item in your custom drupal module(using hook_menu )

2.In page callback for the menu item created in step 1 call the
    function which will be returning the html page your wish to create
    using jquery and php code.

3.Inside the called function use drupal_add_js to add the js code.

A sample code:-

```
function mymodule_menu() {
 $items['abc/def'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
  );
  return $items;
 }

function mymodule_abc_view($ghi = 0, $jkl = '') {
  // use drupal_add_js
  // use own html generating php code

 }
```

Comment: Hi follow up question.I have created a basic page and changed it's URL ALIAS to sample.In my module I have "$items['sample'] = array(//etc.);" this code but when i go to sample page it does not show the html that i create in my module.